# Filtering SQL Server View for better performance

Tags: sql-server, sql-view, sqlperformance, sql-tuning

Is there a performance difference executing the two views? If audit contains millions of records, is there a performance gain by filtering the data inside the view or using the where statement outside the view?

```
select * from vwTestPerformance where AuditId = 5708701

select * from vwTestPerformanceFilteredInside
```

---

```
create view vwTestPerformance
as
select * from Audit
go
```

---

```
create view vwTestPerformanceFilteredInside
as
select * from Audit where AuditId = 5708701
go
```

---

Comment: hoping you don't actually use `select *` ; the columns should be listed. Regarding the speed/performance, what stops you from testing the options? and have you looked at the executions plans?

Comment: If the view is as simple as this then no there is probably no performance difference. You need to look at the query plans to be sure. When a filter at a high level is used at a lower level, it's called 'predicate pushing'

Comment: Need to read up on predicate pushing.

Comment: This select * example was simplified for readability and the query plan shows no differences.  The real life view has some more complexity to it but thought by adding a where statement outside the view it would understand not to pull all records and perform equally as qualifying the where statement on all the selects inside the view.